# pusher without internet connection

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I'm using laravel 5.4 with pusher to build a real-time application , but I have poor internet connection so I'm wondering if I can use a pusher bridge instead and if it doesn't need an internet connection ?

Comment: You want a real time app without internet connection... So is it real time with just your local computer?

Comment: yes it's just i local LAN epascarello

Comment: just like vinkla/pusher @RossWilson

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure another driver for Laravel because Pusher is a third-party service (needs internet), that manages all the web socket server. I also found out this behavior of Pusher and for that, I searched for another driver. **Redis** is the second option. Choosing Redis requires a Websocket server to be configured in order to manage all the connection (Pusher's tasks). This is because Redis only handles the sending of messages to the channels but doesn't do everything that Pusher does.

Install Predis on your Laravel project using this command `composer require predis/predis`.
Install Redis on your local server.
Then install this: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server in order to install a socket.io server implementation compatible with Laravel. (Socket.io will be responsible now for managing the connections into the channels defined in Laravel).

Answer (score 0):

Pusher requires an Internet connection to work unfortunately - however you should know that Pusher can deal with sketchy Internet connections fairly well, so you maybe could give it a try and see how well it works!